# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'focus')

Tags: javascript, focus, typeerror, undefined

[UI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8m2T.png)

When I input 6 digit of verification code then it shows

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'focus')

**The verification code not coming from the server. It's just normal javaScript code for frontend UI**

```
let codes = document.querySelectorAll('.code')

codes[0].focus()

codes.forEach(function (code, idx) {
    code.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.key >= 0 && e.key <= 9) {
            codes[idx].value = ''
            setTimeout(() => codes[idx + 1].focus(), 10)
        } else if (e.key === 'Backspace') {
            setTimeout(() => codes[idx - 1].focus(), 10)
        }
    })
})
```

**What should i use in the javaScript sothat the error will solve**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that either `codes[idx + 1]` or `codes[idx - 1]` is an index that doesn't exist and returns `undefined`. You can add a check before you calling the `focus` method.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  if (typeof codes[idx + 1] !== 'undefined') {
    codes[idx + 1].focus()
  }
}, 10)
```

Or you can use the [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to shorten it.

```
setTimeout(() => codes[idx + 1]?.focus(), 10)
```